# Not getting min attribute value in given elements set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've:

```
for(var k=0;k<10;k++){
    $(eleid).after('<li class="pgs_li_cls" id="stpli_'+k+'" data-pos="'+k+'"><input type="button" value="'+k+'" class="stkpgmb" id="stkpgid_'+k+'" onclick="func_is(this);"></li>');
}

function func_is(ele){
    var max = 0, min=0;
    $('.pgs_li_cls').each(function() {
        max = Math.max($(this).attr("data-pos"), max);
        min = Math.min($(this).attr("data-pos"), min);
    });
    var an_id = ele.id;
    an_id = an_id.substr(0, an_id.length-1);
    $('#stpli_'+min).remove();
    console.log(max+"   "+min);
}
```

As you can see i'm creating `li` containing a button 10 times and which ever button is clicked function `func_is()` is called, So what happens is that when a button is clicked it retrieves the `li` which have the minimum `data-pos` and remove that.

The problem is that for the first time when a button is clicked it find the min result to be `0` and max result to be `10` which is great and then it removes the `li` with minimum `data-pos`.

but when I click another button the `min` value is still 0 as it suppose to be 1 even though `li data-pos 0` has been removed (in my browser inspect after first click can't find the `li` data-pos 0).

I would really appreciate is someone tell what am I doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are initializing min value to 0 in `func_is` function.

Try setting it to bigger value

```
function func_is(ele){
  var max = 0, min= 1000;
```

Comment: Not sure why you think it's weird.  If you're trying to find the smallest number and you *start* with 0, you'll get 0. (assuming all >0).

Comment: @freedomn-m  well, I thought `min = math` might override the old value of min.

Comment: Yes, it does, with the minimum value between the two.  The cleaner option would be to set it to null and check for null in the `min = Math.min` line.